# UIPageControl current page indicator not moving

Tags: objective-c

*Update* There was a hidden UIPageControl and the variable was wired to that one.

I have a UIPageControl, but doesn't matter what value I gave to the currentPage property, the white dot never moves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you remember to connect the UIPageControl to the appropriate IBOutlet in Interface Builder? You can easily check this from the debugger by checking whether the outlet has a value or is nil.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too, my guess is the page control he is trying to set is nil.

Comment: @PeterPeiGuo: That was going to be my next guess